# Defining private static class member

Tags: c++, class, static, member

```
class B { /* ... */ };

class A {
public:
    A() { obj = NULL; }
private:
    static B* obj;
};
```

However this produces huge mass of linker errors that symbol **obj** is unresolved.

What's the "correct" way to have such private static class member without these linker errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define like this :

this is in the header :

```
class B { ... }

class A {
public:
    A() { obj = NULL; }
private:
    static B* obj;
}
```

this is in the source

```
B* A::obj = NULL;
```

Comment: Most probably he doesn't need `A() { obj = NULL; }` then

Comment: @7vies: Not including the A constructor would change the meaning of the code. Currently the construction of a new A object resets the static member obj (which may be important).

Comment: @Martin:  While I agree that taking the initialization of the static member out of the constructor changes the behavior, I am curious why someone would open themselves up to the potential memory leaks this could (and likely would) cause.  If any A object creates a B object on the heap, the next time an A object is created, the B object will be leaked.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add

```
B *A::obj = NULL;
```

to one of your cpp files. Also note that if you set obj in A's constructor, that means that whenever you create an A object you reset obj again - since it is static, there is only one obj that is shared among all A instances.

Answer (score 3):

You have to initialize obj in a cpp file:

```
B* A::obj = NULL;
```

You are not allowed to initialize it in a constructor, since it is a static variable.

Comment: As it happens, he's assigning to it rather than trying to initialise it in the constructor, which is why he gets linker rather than compiler errors.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/ctors.html#faq-10.12

(And as @peoro noted, please remember to end every class definition with a `;`).

Comment: @7vies: That's why that part is a parenthesized PS.

Comment: well, even in parentheses it does not make much sense as he already knows that

Answer (score 1):

Linking errors are because you also need to declare static variables outside class definition purely for linking purpose and static memory allocation as

```
B* A::obj;
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared the static member, but you did not define it.

Further, you set its value whenever any instance of A is constructed, whereas in fact you only want it initialised once.

```
class B;

class A {
private:
    static B* obj;
};

B* A::obj = NULL;
```

As your class A definition is probably in a header file, you should ensure that the definition of obj (that I added) goes in one (and one only) .cpp file. This is because it must appear only once in your compiled project, but the contents of the header file may be `#included` multiple times.